# Match any or range of unicode symbols to any of the following strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match a digit, float or symbol(fractions) followed by an optional space, then: 'tsp', 'teaspoon' or 'teaspoons'.

Here is what I have:

```
/(\d.*|½|⅓|⅔|¼|⅕|⅖|⅗|⅗) ?tsp|\1 ?teaspoons?/gm
```

Here are my current results:

```
1 tsp
// match: 1

2tsp
// match: 2

0.5tsp
// match: 0.5

½teaspoon
// match: undefined

0.5 teaspoons
// match: undefined
```

Desired result:

```
1 tsp
// match: 1

2tsp
// match: 2

0.5tsp
// match: 0.5

½teaspoon
// match: ½

0.5 teaspoons
// match: 0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not work because you are mistaking the function of `\1` as "recurse group 1", whereas it actually means "match what group 1 matched". These two phrases seems similar, but is actually very different.

What you want is "copy and paste group 1, which is `(\d.*|½|⅓|⅔|¼|⅕|⅖|⅗|⅗)` to replace the `\1`", right? This way you don't have to write the whole thing again. However, this is what "recurse group 1" does (usually `\g<1>`), which is not supported by JavaScript regex yet. `\1` means "match whatever group 1 matched". In this case, group 1 would not have matched anything if it goes to the second alternative! Therefore, `\1` matches nothing.

You can either write out group 1 once again:

```
/(\d.*|½|⅓|⅔|¼|⅕|⅖|⅗|⅗) ?tsp|(\d.*|½|⅓|⅔|¼|⅕|⅖|⅗|⅗) ?teaspoons?/gm
```

But this would mean that you would need to check group 1 *or* group 2. If group 1 is empty, check group 2. Fortunately, this regex can be rewritten in one single group:

```
/(\d.*|½|⅓|⅔|¼|⅕|⅖|⅗|⅗) ?(?:tsp|teaspoons?)/gm
```